# How to determine if there is a specific short integer variable value in the array？

Tags: c#

I have an array of integers, and a short integer variable, I want to know if the value of this short integer exists in the array.

I tried using Contains, but I don't support short integer variables, so I can't help it.

```
 public List<Client> GetLogList(string userId,
                                string flagId,
                                string itemId,
                                int[] labIds,
                                string deviceId,
                                int[] actionType,
                                int? signStatus,
                                DateTime? startDate,
                                DateTime? endDate,
                                int pageIndex,
                                int pageSize)
 {
    DB.Queryable<Client, User, Item, Flag, ClientDevice, LogItem>
    ((clientOp, labUser, labItem, rfidFlag, clientDev, labUseLog) =>
      clientOp.DeviceId == clientDev.DeviceId 
       && clientOp.Operator == labUser.UserId 
       && clientOp.FlagId == rfidFlag.FlagId 
       && rfidFlag.ItemId == labItem.ItemId 
       && clientOp.Id == labUseLog.Id)
                .WhereIF(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId), clientOp => 
                 clientOp.Operator == userId)
                .WhereIF(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(flagId), clientOp => 
                 clientOp.FlagId == flagId)
                .WhereIF(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemId), rfidFlag => 
                 rfidFlag.ItemId == Convert.ToInt32(itemId))
                .WhereIF(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(deviceId), clientOp => 
                 clientOp.DeviceId == deviceId)
                .WhereIF(actionType != null && actionType.Count() > 0, 
                 clientOp => clientOp.ActionType.Contains(actionType)))
 }
```

Comment: You can see the last piece of code. "ClientOp.ActionType" is a short integer variable. "actiontype" is an array of integers. I want to know if there is a short integer value in the array, but I can't use Contains. So I want to know if there is a way to solve my problem?

Comment: I think you're just doing things the wrong way around, from your description. At the moment, you're trying to write code that asks "does this short integer variable contain this int array?" which doesn't match what you've narratively said you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, my English is not very good, so I may not express my meaning. I have found a solution to this problem. There is a method in the ORM framework that can help me solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: And it wasn't just to write `actionType.Contains(clientOp.ActionType)`?